How exactly mutually shared electrons revolves around nucleuses?
In the first year, this question stroked my brain again. I have asked this question to my chemistry teacher on how exactly shared electrons move when it forms a covalent bond. He said, it is maybe like infinity ♾️ in informal but I'm not exactly sure about that. If they move only within the parent atom, then covalent bond between the atoms isn't possible but we know that covalent bonds exist so this assumption is incorrect. Please note that I'm talking about shared valence electrons in last energy level on how they move?

It would be "nuclei" and quantum mechanics makes your question nonsensical. Just read about orbital and forget some wacky planetary models.
